# Is there a author_update action?

Tags: hooks, author, actions

Is there an action you can tie into whenever an authors information is updated. (ie they update their display name). If not is there any way to tie into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [`edit_user_profile_update`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile_update) and [`personal_options_update`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/personal_options_update) actions that runs after a user is updated, with access to the user object. There's also a variable `update_{$meta_type}_meta` action that runs when meta of type `user` is updated.

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. I guess I didn't see it since I was searching for 'author'. Thanks.

Comment: You can restrict it to authors with [`user_can()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/user_can) and the appropriate [capability](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) (for instance, if `user_can( $id, 'edit_published_posts' )` returns `true`, you know that the user's level is *at least* author).

Comment: I notice that edit_user_profile_update get's called prior to the update. This means that I'm not able to find out the new 'display_name' for the author. Is there a way to get this? It looks like WP only passes in the user_id into the callback function.